# jest test toast fires onClick

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a basic component, how can I create a jest test to check the `react-toastify`
 appears?

My test so far, how can I check the toast has fired?:

```
it("Check toast appears", () => {
    const button = shallow(<FormFail />);
    button.find("button").simulate("click");
    expect(mockCallBack.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
});
```

Component:

```
class FormFail extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  onClick(event) {
    console.log(toast);
    toast.error("Fail", {
      position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Container className="App">
          <Button value="button" color="primary" onClick={this.onClick}>
            Press for Fail Toast
          </Button>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The toast appears as:

```
<div class="Toastify"><div class="Toastify__toast-container Toastify__toast-container--top-right" style="pointer-events: none;"></div></div>
```

Comment: That component doesn't get `onClick` from `props`, so it's unclear where you think the mock function is going.

Comment: Im new to jest, how would I check my onclick fires a toast?

Comment: Did you try to change `button.find("button").simulate("click");` to `button.find("Button").simulate("click");`?

Comment: How do I look for the Toast and confirm its visible?